# Java - Asynchronous reading?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, synchronization

**The server:** There's a server that holds an array of data that can be marked by a certain client (which is given a color by the server). So, it's supposed to take an event by the client, process it, and update all the clients with the new state of the array. The array is a minesweeper stage all the clients share.

**The client:** It has several buttons, each referring to a position in the array. Whenever a button is pressed, it first synchronizes with the server (using [Cristian's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristian%27s_algorithm)), then an event is sent to the server. It should also wait to receive an update anytime, and when that happens, the buttons should be updated too.

**The problem:** What should I do if I want the client to be permanently waiting for an update and not mix itself with any other receiving data? Say if the client receives a `Long` for synchronizing the clock, whatever is waiting to receive an update client-wise shouldn't receive the `Long`.

Thank you beforehand!

EDIT: I'm using TCP as my protocol. Also, I added some pseudocode on how the server and the client manage the events.

With some pseudocode I should explain this better:

Game `main()`

```
Create an event handler, and make it run as a separate thread
while amount of players < 2
    Receive a connection
    Create an instance that represents the player
    Send the player some data it will need
    Register the player as an observer of the game
end while
for each player
    Tell them the game is ready to start
    Make the player run in a separate thread
end for each
Mark the game as started
Notify each of the observers about the game
```

Player `run()`

```
while true
    Wait for a time request
    Send the player the current time
    Wait for a button click
    Insert the event into a global list of events
end while
```

Event handler `run()`

```
while true
    Wait 50 ms
    Order the event list by the time marks
    Get and remove the first element in the list
    Tell the game the button was pressed, also tell it who pressed it
    Ask the game to notify the observers
end while
```

Currently, my client does this:

Client `main()`

```
Connect to the server
Receive the basic needed data
Wait for a confirmation to start the game
Receive the stage (an array with the positions in the server)
Display one button for each element in the received array
Append an action listener to the button
if the button is pressed
    Request the current time to the server
    Adjust the time
    Send a button click event to the server
    Wait to receive the stage again
    Update the stage
end if
```

And here comes the problem. How do I separate the moment where the server receives the time and the stage so neither can look to each other? I mean, the server can send the time or the stage in any order and the client should know what it's receiving. I'm lost and I don't know what to do here...

Comment: Uh. Mind to tell me why I got downvoted? I'm seriously lost here...

Comment: (I did not downvote, but) it's hard to answer meaningfully with a question this high-level/abstract. You haven't shown any code, or pseudocode, or mentioned any socket protocols you're using (anything higher-level than TCP/UDP?). You mention things like "colors" and "buttons" (completely abstract) and also talk about solving the much more concrete problem of time synchronization.

Comment: OH! Well, good point, I forgot to show some code (although all I need is the general idea, not the exact code). But I can specify some few things. Thank you, I'll fix right away.

Comment: On top of that, I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean in the last sentence. Are you saying that you want two separate channels of communication between the server and each client, so "general" data does not get mixed with "time sync" data? If so, then _you_ need to design this, or use a protocol with does that for you.

Comment: I had a hard time trying to put it into words too. But I'll explain this better with some pseudocode.

Comment: Done, I added some pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at or considered JMS? You can refer to [JAVA EE 6 DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html) to get started with JMS.

Comment: While reading a bit about JMS (which I didn't know existed, thank you!), I thought of using multiple channels. Let's see what I can come off with!

Comment: Some basic tips. You're looking to send "Objects" not just texts. So make your objects implement serializable. For your needs, you need a Queue and not a Topic. Also look at Acknowledgement properties.

Comment: Actually what I didn't know, and what I should use, is that the incoming object has, and knows, the kind of class it is! So, I can actually tell the client to do something based on what kind of message it received.

Comment: "Wait for a confirmation to start the game"
"Wait to receive the stage again"
What kind of messages are you looking to get as confirmation and stage? Objects? So the classes that create these objects need to be sent from the producer to the consumer. Upon receipt, you use them (stage) and then carry out your updates.
Try with a simple example like a Hello World example with JMS. Then you'll figure out what to do with your application.